# Show each array values in input box if they are set

Tags: php

If i had enter all value in say four input boxes with name `prod[]` and when i click on the submit button, i want to show each values without loosing it if the array values are isset.

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) { ?> <tr> 
<td style="width:50% !important;">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="PprodName[]" />
</td>
```

Comment: Post your current code before asking help.

Comment: It's unreadable as comment. Edit your post and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

**@QaisarSatti**
thanks bro but i think i just got the logic. here is my code :

```
<?php
    $j = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i<=8; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
    <td style="width:50% !important;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ppr<?php echo $i; ?>" name="PprodName[]" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['PprodName'][$j] ) ? $_POST['PprodName'][$j] : ''; ?>" />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $j++; } ?>
```

mark this checked if you found it useful. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['PprodName'];


foreach( $name as $v ) {
echo $v;
}
```